# How do I install CiviCRM on Backdrop?

Tags: installation, backdrop

Given that the answer to [whether CiviCRM will work with Backdrop](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/264/will-civicrm-work-with-backdrop) is Yes, and that the integration is "[functionally complete](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/11475/26)" -- how do I install CiviCRM on an existing Backdrop site?

It is not included in the wiki instructions yet, and when I download the latest Civi 4.7.x Backdrop tarball from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/) and try to follow the Drupal 7 instructions on **/modules/civicrm/install/** I get an error:

> This installer can only be used for the Drupal version of CiviCRM.

I have been successful in generating a localhost Backdrop version with buildkit but not installing on a site that is not on localhost.

Comment: At the risk of asking a more existential question: why? What does backdrop offer that Drupal7 doesn't? You may find yourself with a large support burden for a rarely used integration.

Comment: What does Backdrop offer over Drupal7? A future, and a particular focus on the small-medium nonprofit sector for starters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since this answer, [@herb](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/207/herb) has expanded on this in the Wiki. See "[Installing CiviCRM for Backdrop CMS](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Backdrop+CMS)"

There is now an official version of [CiviCRM for Backdrop](https://civicrm.org/download/list). Once CiviCRM code is placed in /modules, go to

`http://MYWEBSITE.COM/modules/civicrm/install/index.php?civicrm_install_type=backdrop`

to install. Note the flag to tell the installer that we're installing for Backdrop otherwise it'll not recognize it.

---

The code changes to get the installer working for Backdrop is almost done (it's waiting to be tested and merged in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8177). You've got three options:

1. Install manually: run the civicrm.mysql queries on your database (in /modules/civicrm/sql/) and manually build the civicrm.settings.php file (from /modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template) and put it in your webroot (same level as settings.php).
2. Apply the patches above to tarball you downloaded (plus apply this patch https://github.com/backdrop/backdrop/commit/93ecec4c081002bfc46fec421b5642d496ca3dac to backdrop. Then navigate to example.com/modules/civicrm/install/index.php?civicrm_install_type=backdrop to run the Backdrop-specific installer.
3. Or, wait until the next CiviCRM 4.7.x minor release and Backdrop 1.x minor release and it should be working well enough. (Use the same url: example.com/modules/civicrm/install/index.php?civicrm_install_type=backdrop)