# CiviCRM on Backdrop - Oops incorrect Drupal version

Tags: backdrop

Oracle VM

Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa

LAMP through Mint

Backdrop v1.18.1

CiviCRM 5.35.1 for Backdrop

I go to http://localhost and get Backdrop just fine.

I go to http://localhost/modules/civicrm/install/index.php and get "Oops! Incorrect CiviCRM version ... can only be used for Drupal version of CiviCRM".

I downloaded CiviCRM 5.35.1 for Backdrop three times, extracted, placed folder into modules and get that same message.

Clearly it is installed correctly or I wouldn't be getting that message. Perhaps the Backdropcms version and the CiviCRM version are not compatible?

/module/civicrm/README.md says it is good for Drupal, Wordpress and Joomla.
but
/module/civicrm/install/index.php line 67 says acceptable are "drupal, wordpress, backdrop"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

John in Medford, Oregon

Comment: Hi John -- have you tried this one? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/11716/26

Comment: Key point: `http://localhost/modules/civicrm/install/index.php?civicrm_install_type=backdrop`

Comment: I wound up editing var/www/html/modules/civicrm/install/index.php

Line 76, which sets the install Else type

$installtype = 'backdrop';

Thanks Laryn for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Giving credit to Laryn, but not sure how to do that other than this.

Key point: http://localhost/modules/civicrm/install/index.php?civicrm_install_type=backdrop – Laryn - CEDC.org 22 hours ago